# How to convert Samsung's motion photos to still photos?

Tags: batch, photos, imagemagick

I've taken a bunch of photos on my Samsung Galaxy phone after inadvertently activating the "motion photo" mode, which captures a short video clip before and after the "click", instead of a still photo.

I now have the JPG files on my computer, and would like to batch turn them into still photos (while keeping the metadata).

How can I do that?
I was thinking of using ImageMagick but couldn't find anything on this topic.

Here's what appears in the Windows Photo app upon opening the JPG files:

[image]

Clicking the "MOTION" label will play the short video clip.

And it is a proper JPEG file (with a JPEG file header), not just a video file with a .JPG extension. It must be that the short video clip is somehow embedded in the JPG file format. The file opens normally as a still picture in all applications (e.g. Paint).

Comment: "I now have the JPG files on my computer." Then you have the still photos, unless the JPG extension is a misnomer. JPG is not used for video.

Comment: They are JPG files. See my edit. To people voting to close, please explain why.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. However, I am asking how to process the files on my computer. That they were produced by a mobile device isn't that relevant. Anyway, I did end up finding a solution which I posted below.

Comment: @XavierPoinas Fair enough. Upvoted the question and answer and retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "motion photos", the short MP4 video clip is added to the JPEG trailer.

The clip can be stripped out by the ExifTool program:
https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=10133.0

```
exiftool -trailer:all= *.jpg
```

Being a command-line tool it is easy to process the files in batches.

Comment: Wow! You learn something new every day! +1

Comment: I figured it had to be some sort of metadata. I'd imagine that IrfanView's batch processor could probably do something like this too.

Comment: After executing the command in a photo, still appears the "Motion" button on the top left corner of the image. I suppose it is because Windows Photos detect the image as a motion image. 
Is there any way to edit the photo metadata to set the photo as not containing motion image?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure, as I was only concerned about the file size. But mine doesn't seem to show as "Motion" anymore in Windows Photos.