Can't get FFmpeg to convert Samsung Motion Photos from JPEG to MP4
I pulled a bunch of Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra motion photos to my PC (Windows 11) for video editing, but they were in JPEG, and for some reason Microsoft Clipchamp couldn't convert them to video. But, I knew the motion photos were intact, because Microsoft Photos was showing the MOTION option and playing the videos just fine.
So, I'm in FFmpeg just throwing everything at the wall, but can only get still MP4's out of it, with none of the video.
Here's the breakdown of what I'm looking at for: ffmpeg -i input.jpg
Input #0, image2, from '20240623_233601.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 874324 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2944x2208 [SAR 59:59 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn

So to get the whole folder converted, I'm trying:
for %i in (*.jpg) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -c:v libx264 -map 0:0 -preset veryslow -crf 18 "%~ni.mp4"

But this just results in a bunch of those still MP4's I mentioned.
I'm assuming the problem starts with that odd duration of 00:00:00.04, with a bitrate of 874324 kb/s, but I'm not sure. I don't understand this mjpeg video format very well at all.
I been trying to work through this with copilot to no success, and so I'm turning to Super User in case anyone can help me out.

Maybe a good option would be to upload the motion photos on your phone to Google Photos and then you can download them on your computer as MOV files (see https://xdaforums.com/t/converting-assembling-samsungs-motion-photos-from-apples-live-photos-or-any-photo-and-video-file.4262965/)

From this question (https://superuser.com/questions/1828734/how-to-convert-samsungs-motion-photos-to-still-photos) we learn that motion photos use the trailer metadata to store the motion data in the jpeg file. You're probably telling ffmpeg to use the basic jpeg data, and instead you need to tell it to use the trailer data. Not sure how that would work, but this info should help you figure out the correct process.

Here's a more advanced walk through explaining how the image and video data are structured within the file and giving *nix solutions for pulling these apart: https://medium.com/android-news/working-with-motion-photos-da0aa49b50c

You can also do Export on the phone gallery app, and choose video, https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-turn-off-motion-photo-samsung/#:~:text=To%20send%20it%20as%20a,Video%2C%20according%20to%20your%20preferences.

@music2myear You put me on the right track. So exiftool can remove the video from the jpeg, but can also remove the jpeg from the video, which is exactly what i needed. So using the following batch script: for %%f in (*.jpg) do (     exiftool -b -EmbeddedVideoFile "%%f" > "%%~nf.mp4" )
I was able to get perfect MP4 files with the jpegs leftover! :D

Nice. Write that up as an answer and post it down below!
